# How to access a column in a dataframe when column name is stored in a variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access a column and find some statistics of this column, but, the name of the column is stored as a variable and that gives me an error. Let me elaborate -

I have a dataframe `df` and it has many columns which only take 0/1 as the value. For example: Column `sex,smoker,employed` I want to do this -

> df.sex.value_counts()

and it gives the frequency of 0 and 1.

> 1  750
>
> 0  876

Now, I want to dymanically allot the name of a variable to another variable

when `var could be sex or smoker or employed` and when `var='smoker'` then the code should give statistics of smoker

> df.var.value_counts()

But, I cannot do that, understandably so, and I get an error:

```
AttributeError, 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'var'
```

How can I still use the above command `df.var.value_counts()` dynamically

Comment: `df[var]`.......

Comment: Thanks Coldspeed. I just thought that there might have been a way to use the variable column name this way and that's what my question was all about.     df[var] I totally agree with.